# What is the difference between Black Souls and White Souls?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages and disadvantages of each version of Azura's Star?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-each-version-of-azuras-star)

I am on the Star of Azura quest and I am at the part where you need to decide whether you are going to fill it with Black Souls or White Souls. What's the difference?

Comment: racist! (12 chars)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Black souls are NPC souls (bandits, city guards, merchants, farmers, etc.); white souls are everything else.

Normally you cannot capture a black soul unless you have a black soul gem (which are hard to find), or the Black Star. Either version of Azura's Star will function as a reusable grand soul gem, however only the Black Star will allow you to capture black souls (and, although it may be a bug, it also will capture white souls).

Regardless of level, a black soul is equivalent in power to a grand soul, making it easier to get your most powerful enchantments by taking out easy bandit camps. My personal recommendation is to get the Black Star, especially with its current behavior to also capture white souls.

Comment: @desaivv Because creatures with black souls are so much more abundant it offsets them.

Comment: @desaivv Enchantments made using black souls are equivalent to those using white _grand_ souls, yes -- all black souls are equivalent to grand souls, regardless of the level of the NPC you got it from, which makes black souls great for high-level enchantments early on, before you're capable of killing creatures with grand souls. Black soul gems are hard to find because their use is deemed unethical at best; the College of Winterhold even bans them outright, although Enthir (who seems to fancy himself a smuggler) can sell you some. http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Soul_Gem

Answer (score 2):

Black souls are human souls. White souls are everything else. Black souls are a lot bigger then the white souls. Bring the star to the wizard so you can use the black souls.

Comment: "living humanoid", actually. Mer and the beast races (Khajiit, Argonians) also have black souls. Undead (Draugr) seem to have white souls, 'though.

Comment: @JoachimSauer The other exception is that Falmer have white souls, despite being a Mer race.

Answer (score 1):

The dark star can be filled black souls and white souls so it's recommended to get him instead of Azura's star.